# How to clear buffer of SScursor using pymysql?

Tags: python, pymysql

I tried the following codes (from pymysql test code):
https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/pymysql/tests/test_cursor.py

```
def test_cleanup_rows_unbuffered(self):

    conn = self.test_connection
    cursor = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.SSCursor)

    cursor.execute("select * from test as t1, test as t2")
    for counter, row in enumerate(cursor):
        print(row)
        if counter > 10:
            break

    del cursor
    self.safe_gc_collect()

    print('The second cursor.')
    c2 = conn.cursor()

    c2.execute("select 1")
    self.assertEqual(c2.fetchone(), (1,))
    self.assertIsNone(c2.fetchone())
```

But the code keeps running and never stops after "print(row)". Or should I say it never moves on to the second cursor.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Hello You have to run `fetchall()` command  . You can enumerate this to do the operations required later. SO your program should look something like below.

```
for counter, row in enumerate(cursor.fetchall()):
        print(row)
        if counter > 10:
            break
```